# Prevent autoescaping custom template tags in django

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading my old project to latest versions of python/django and am having trouble with custom template tags.

Template tag definition:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def my_tag(*args) -> str:
    """ returns html code """

register.simple_tag(lambda *x: my_tag("hello world", *x), name='my_tag')
```

Example tag usage:

```
{% my_tag "this no longer works, this autoescapes my code" %}
```

How can I modify my tag definition to prevent autoescaping, so that I don't have to modify templates:

```
{% autoescape off %}{% my_tag "workaround, this doesn't autoescape html" %}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mark result safe with [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) method:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
def my_tag(*args) -> str:
    return mark_safe(result)
```